# AngularJS won't validate input on form elements that are ng-show hidden

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm working on an accordion like registration form and every time I progress to the next step of registration by hiding the first part of the form and expanding the next with ng-show, the elements on vm.registerForm.(elementName) are undefined. From what I read in the documentation angular only applies a class to these elements, so why are they undefined when validating a form at the final step?

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

HTML Template:

```
<form name="vm.registerForm">
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section expanded"
       ng-show="vm.formList.indexOf('playerInfo') != -1 || vm.formList.indexOf('login') != -1">
    <div class="section-title" ng-click="vm.gotoMode('playerInfo')">User info</div>
    <div class="section-content" ng-show="vm.mode.playerInfo || vm.mode.login">

      <div class="flex-form">
        <div class="flex-form-group" ng-if="vm.mode.playerInfo">
          <label>Already have an account? Just log in!</label>
          <div class="button" ng-click="vm.gotoMode('login')">Log in</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group dummy"></div>
        <div class="flex-form-group dummy"></div>
        <div class="flex-form-group dummy"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-form" ng-if="vm.mode.playerInfo">
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="user_name">Username</label>
          <input username-checker type="text" ng-model="vm.username" name="user_name">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="first">First name</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="vm.firstName" name="first" ng-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="last">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="vm.lastName" name="last" ng-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group" ng-if="vm.gameManager.game.name == 'League of Legends'">
          <label for="summoner">Summoner Name</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="vm.summoner" name="summoner" summoner>
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" ng-model="vm.email" name="email" ng-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="birthday">Day of birth (MM/DD/YYYY)</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="vm.birthday" name="birthday" ng-required="true" birthdate>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <select ng-model="vm.sex" name="sex" ng-required="true">
            <option value="">Gender</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
            <option value="not_specified">Prefer not to answer</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="zip">Zip code</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="vm.zip" name="zipcode" ng-required="true" zipcode>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone number (optional)</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="vm.phone" name="phone" ng-required="false" phone-number>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" ng-model="vm.password" name="password" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="20">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <label for="password2">Password (again)</label>
          <input type="password" ng-model="vm.password2" name="password2" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="20">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <div class="checkbox-holder">
            <input class='checkbox' type="checkbox" name='showPlayerName' ng-model="vm.showPlayerName">
            <label for="full_name">Show Real Name on Bracket</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <div class="checkbox-holder">
            <input class='checkbox' type="checkbox" name='type' value="true" ng-model="vm.type">
            <label for="spec">Spectator</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">
          <div class="checkbox-holder">
            <input class='checkbox' type="checkbox" id='accept' value="true" ng-required="vm.regMode != 'user'"
                   ng-model="vm.accept">
            <label for="accept">Accept Terms of Service</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-form-group">

          <a class="aside-link" href="" ng-click="vm.showTOS = true">View TOS</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Continue -->
      <div class="button" ng-click="vm.next()" ng-if="!(vm.formList.length - 1 == vm.modeIterator)">
        Next
      </div>

      <!-- If there aren't anymore steps to complete -->
      <div class="button" ng-click="vm.next()" ng-if="(vm.formList.length - 1 == vm.modeIterator)">
        Confirm
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-section" ng-class="{expanded: vm.mode.teams}" ng-if="vm.formList.indexOf('payment') != -1">
    <div class="section-title" ng-click="vm.gotoMode('teams'); vm.gotoTeamMode('preference')">Teams</div>
    <div class="section-content">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Validation Code:

```
function userFormValid() {
  var valid = false;
  if (vm.regMode == "user") {
    valid = true;
  } else if (vm.regMode == "anon" || vm.regMode == "admin") {
    // All the parts of the form.
    valid = vm.registerForm.zipcode.$valid && vm.registerForm.first.$valid && vm.registerForm.last.$valid;
    valid &= vm.registerForm.email.$valid && vm.registerForm.sex.$valid && vm.registerForm.birthday.$valid;
    valid &= (vm.accept == true) && vm.registerForm.user_name.$valid && vm.registerForm.password.$valid;
    valid &= vm.password == vm.password2;
    valid &= vm.registerForm.password2.$valid;

    // Let's show a message if this is invalid
    if (vm.password != vm.password2) {
      vm.showMessage('Passwords must match.');
      return false;
    }
  }


  return valid;
}
```

Running the above function at the end of registration will not show any of the elements as defined.

Comment: What is the value of `vm.mode.playerInfo` when your values are undefined?

Comment: `vm.mode.playerInfo` is false when values are undefined. Been going through the angular.js library looking at NgModelController and FormController trying to see where and why these values would be removed for ng-show toggling.

Comment: Well looks like you've found it... Wow. Can't believe I looked in the lib first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked an ng-if that was further down in the DOM. If anyone is wondering, the angular.js FromController does not remove an NgModelController unless the child scope of an element is destroyed.